# Unable to create appropriate selectors to parse some information

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors

I have written a script in python using css selector to parse some names and phone numbers from a webpage. The script I have created is not giving me the results I expect ; rather, some information that i don't want are also coming along. How to rectify my selectors so that it will uniquely parse only the name and the phone number and nothing else. For your consideration I've pasted a link containing html elements at the bottom. Thanks in advance.

Here is what I've written:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
root = fromstring(html)
for tree in root.cssselect(".cbFormTableEvenRow"):
    try:
        name = tree.cssselect(".cbFormDataCell span.cbFormData")[0].text
    except:
        name = ""
    try:
        phone = tree.cssselect(".cbFormLabel:contains('Phone Number')+td.cbFormDataCell .cbFormData")[0].text
    except:
        phone = ""
    print(name,phone)
```

Results I expect:

```
JAYMES CARTER (402)499-8846
```

Results I'm getting:

```
1840390831 
RESIDENTIAL 
JAYMES CARTER (402)499-8846
  
None 
My valuation jumped by almost $60,000 in one year. There are multiple comparable properties nearby that are much lower than my $194,300 evaluation, and a lot closer to my 2016 year evaluation of $134,400.
```

Link to the html file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/64apg5cjpssd3hb/html_table.html?dl=0

Comment: why don't use xpath ?

Answer (score 1):

Find the `tr` element that is the grandparent of the `span` whose text is 'Phone Number'. From there, get the `td` elements of the desired items and follow the hierarchy down from these to their texts.

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> root = fromstring(open('html_table.html').read())
>>> grand_parent = root.xpath('.//td[contains(text(),"Phone Number")]/..')[0]
>>> grand_parent.xpath('td[1]/span/text()')[0]
'JAYMES CARTER'
>>> grand_parent.xpath('td[5]/span/text()')[0]
'(402)499-8846'
```

Addendum in response to comment:

```
>>> items = grand_parent.xpath('.//span[@class="cbFormData"]/text()')
['JAYMES CARTER', '\xa0', '(402)499-8846']
>>> items = grand_parent.xpath('.//span[@class="cbFormData"]/text()')
>>> [_.replace('\xa0', '').strip() for _ in items]
['JAYMES CARTER', '', '(402)499-8846']
```

Comment: Thanks Bill Bell, for your answer. +1 for this. The thing is there are above 4000 tables in that website and it is necessary to make a post request to reach there. So I didn't paste here the link. Btw, I could only accept this as an answer if you didn't use the `indexing` in your xpath cause the data i'm after need not to be always in the same position. Thanks.

Comment: OK, but I think you'd need to give us more information. You could try the code in the addendum which starts with `grand_parent`. If the telephone numbers are all of the North American pattern then you might select the first item as the name and then watch for a matching item as the telephone number.